# How do I make a Jquery loop of code repeat

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a button that makes the background color change from white to yellow, and when the button is clicked again, it changes back to white. I'm using Jquery to achieve this, but I'm running into a problem when doing a Loop Function. I have a JSfiddle set up with the same code I have here below. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ThemeJared/37RW4/)

----- HTML -----

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
            <div class="button"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---- CSS ----

```
.button {
    background-color: #00ccff;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 25%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5em;
}

.body{
    background-color: white;
}
```

---- JQUERY ----

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var click = false;
        (function loop(){
        if ('click = false') {
            $('.button').click(function () {
                $('body').css("background-color", "yellow");
                click = true;
            });
        } else {
            $('.button').click(function () {
                $('body').css("background-color", "white");
                click = false;
            });
        }
        })();
});
```

Comment: How about just add/remove css class? ` $('.button').click(function () {
          $('body').toggleClass('active');
      });` http://jsfiddle.net/53ehc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var click = false;

            $('.button').click(function () {
               if(click == false){
                $('body').css("background-color", "yellow");
                click = true;
               }else{
              $('body').css("background-color", "white");
                click = false;
               } 
            });         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isWhite = true;
    $(".button").click(function() {
        $('body').css("background-color", (isWhite = !isWhite) ? "white" : "yellow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it allows you to add as many colors as you want ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/37RW4/2/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var bg = 0,
        colors = ['yellow', 'white'],
        len = colors.length;
    $('.button').click(function () {
        $('body')
            .removeClass(colors.join(' '))
            .addClass(colors[bg++ % len]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste and check this exmple i worked for you, I used the toggle effect and i changed some of your code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .button {
    background-color: #00ccff;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 25%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5em;
}

</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js">
</script>


    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="button" id="kot"></div>
            <input type="button" value="Button" class="thebutton">
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                  $(".thebutton").toggle(
                    function(){$("#kot").css({"background-color":"red"});},
                    function(){$("#kot").css({"background-color":"blue"});},
                    function(){$("#kot").css({"background-color":"green"});
                  });
                });
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```